# Transpose one row to column in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, transpose

Consider the following table: I have some values for each state per `year` and `age`.

| Age | Year | State1 | State2 | State3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2010 | 123 | 456 | 789 |
| 2 | 2010 | 111 | 222 | 333 |
| 1 | 2011 | 444 | 555 | 666 |
| 2 | 2011 | 777 | 888 | 999 |

Now I'd like to transpose the table in such a way, that the `Year` becomes the columns:

| Age | State | 2010 | 2011 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | State1 | 123 | 444 |
| 1 | State2 | 456 | 555 |
| 1 | State3 | 789 | 666 |
| 2 | State1 | 111 | 777 |
| 2 | State2 | 222 | 888 |
| 2 | State3 | 333 | 999 |

I can't get it to work, to transpose only that specific column.

What would be a good solution to achieve this in Pandas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can stack and unstack your dataframe:

```
out = (
    df.set_index(["Age", "Year"])
    .stack()
    .unstack("Year")
    .reset_index()
    .rename(columns={"level_1": "State"})
)

Year  Age   State  2010  2011
0       1  State1   123   444
1       1  State2   456   555
2       1  State3   789   666
3       2  State1   111   777
4       2  State2   222   888
5       2  State3   333   999
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is `pd.melt`

we can use this along with a combination of applying a custom index & unstack

```
df1 = pd.melt(df,id_vars=['Year','Age'],var_name=['State'])

out = df1.set_index([df1.groupby(['Year']).cumcount(),'Year','State','Age'])\
                  .unstack('Year').droplevel(0,1).reset_index([1,2])
```

---

```
Year   State  Age  2010  2011
0     State1    1   123   444
1     State1    2   111   777
2     State2    1   456   555
3     State2    2   222   888
4     State3    1   789   666
5     State3    2   333   999
```